# Error Shows up when I press the Enter Key-- How can I ignore the enter key and then keep inputting?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

In this code I'm inputting as many integers as I want, and then pressing the enter key twice to end the program and get the Maximum Value of all the integers I just input. However, if my first input is the enter key, an error shows up. How do I fix this error (using while and if)so that the code will ignore it and let me keep inputting numbers? Thank you everyone.

```
print("Please put in some integers and hit the enter key twice to finish：")
s = input()
first = True
while s != "":          
    lst = s.split()     
    for x in lst:
        if first:       
            maxV = int(x)
            first = False
        else:
            if maxV < int(x):
                maxV = int(x)
    s = input()
print(maxV)
```

Comment: Are you forced to accept input multiple times, instead of just once on a single line?

Comment: Yes, the inputs are each put on a new line, instead of all at once on a single line

Comment: Your code also accepts multiple numbers per line, right?

Comment: Yes, it does accept that

Comment: What should the reported maximum be if the user doesn't enter any numbers? Raising an error may be the *right* thing to do in that situation (though you might want to raise a specific error with a nice explanation, rather than whatever error you're getting now). Compare `max([])`, which raises a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, a word on `input()` and the *Enter* key! Pressing enter is *just* the way you tell `input()` that you’re done writing whatever text you want. When that happens, `input()` grabs the content of the line and sends it as a string to your program.

Therefore, saying that your program crashes if your first input is the enter key isn’t really accurate. The important part is that you wrote nothing before hitting enter, not the act of hitting enter itself. Since you wrote nothing the line is empty, which means `input()` returns a string containing nothing, an empty string. It’s the empty string, as I will show below, not the innocent enter key, which is at fault here.

Now, let’s take a look at what’s causing the error. You haven’t actually shared the exact error message, but I’m certain that it mentions something about `maxV` being undefined.

As we just saw, if you don’t write anything when first prompted for input then `s` is the empty string. As a result, you skip the `while` loop and land directly on the line `print(maxV)`. Since you didn’t enter the `while` loop, however, your program has never heard of `maxV` at that point. When it goes looking for the variable `maxV` it finds nothing, and sensibly throws an error.

---

Here is how I would refactor your program:

```py
import math

max_val = - math.inf

prompt_text = 'Enter one or more numbers, or enter nothing to quit: '

curr_line = input(prompt_text).strip()

while curr_line != '':
    curr_line_vals = (int(curr_val) for curr_val in curr_line.split())
    curr_line_max = max(curr_line_vals)
    max_val = max(max_val, curr_line_max)
    curr_line = input(prompt_text).strip()

print(f'maximum value: {max_val}')
```

Do note that the program above does not verify input at all, that's something to keep in mind. `max_val` has a default value of minus infinity, which means the code won't crash if the user quits without having entered any numbers.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: This is all so clear, I can't thank you enough. I'm trying every iteration of while, if, else to get it to not skip the while loop, to not go directly to print(maxV) but every iteration of that has been wrong

Comment: @DianaA Well, why don’t you want it to skip to the end of the program? The empty string is already how you signal your program to stop, right?

Comment: @DianaA I added the previously mentioned example code, let me know what you think :)